# fetched website url from sql server in asp.net is not clickable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am working in asp.net web form where i am retrieving the link from database and assigning that link to asp label and than i am putting that in hyperlink tag but is not working the hyperlink appear as a text and also its not hiding behind the image.And the link redirect me to the index page.Here is the asplabel and link

```
<a href="<%#facebook %>" >
<img src="facebook_icon.gif" />
      <asp:Label ID="facebook" runat ="server"></asp:Label>
             </a>

 facebook.Text = reader["Facebook"].ToString();
```

Comment: I am new to asp.net and i searched alot to find out even in stack overflow the question is helpful instead of putting this question on hold you people provide me the link and than say this that this one has already an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

**HTML**

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="facebook" runat ="server" ImageUrl="facebook_icon.gif"></asp:HyperLink>
```

**CODE**

```
facebook.NavigateUrl = reader["Facebook"].ToString();
```

Comment: ok let me try this but i think i have tried this anyhow i am going to try again

Comment: not working same problem it shows me the simple text and a seprate icon

Comment: Updated  the answer please check...

Comment: now another error arise Requested URL: /cvskils/resume/orange/System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label Server Error in '/cvskils' Application.

Comment: the link is redirected to this link

Comment: Did you replace the previous html code (`<a>` to `</a>` tag) and keep only the code given in the answer (`asp:HyperLink`), or replaced only the label?

Comment: Thanks buddy i didnt correct out my mistake before the answer you give is hundered % correct thanks alot